# Inter parameters in decorator for typescript

Tags: typescript

Below is an example program that creates a decorator `decorate` and applies it to a class member. The `decorate` decorator is meant to accept the same parameters as the class member. However, this program compiles because I've forced inference on the `T` generic for the decorator to `any`.

I am looking for an approach which properly infers the arguments to the decorator function and makes compilation fail because `doesNotExist` is not a valid member of the first argument to the method.

```
function decorate<T extends (...args:any) => any>(fn: (...args: Parameters<T>) => void) {
    return (target: any, propertyName: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) => {
        descriptor.value = function (...args: Parameters<T>) { fn(...args) }
        return descriptor;
    }
}

class Foo {
    // arg should be inferred to { qux: string } and compilation should fail
    @decorate(arg => {
        console.log(arg.doesNotExist);
    })
    bar(baz: { qux: string }) {
        console.log('orig');
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible, If you are willing to add an explcit annotation to `arg` we can validate that `arg` and `baz` have the same type.

Comment: Yeah, even if we made the `T` more "inferrable" by making it a tuple, there's no good way to get a generic curried function to infer anything from what's passed into its return value. e.g., `const f = <T>() => (x: T) => x` isn't going to return a `string` for `f()("hey")`, so I don't think we can expect the type of `arg` to be inferred from the type of `baz`.

Comment: See [microsoft/TypeScript#2607](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2607), specifically [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2607#issuecomment-168910291)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. My experiments around this have indicated that T itself is inferred properly if I change `any` in `TypedPropertyDescriptor` to `T` but then I need to remove the `extends` for the `decorate` and as a result can't use `Parameters<T>` because that complains that `T` is not of type `(...args: any[]) => any`.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution, @RomanShtylman?